# How to make Select one menu Unselectable/Unchangeable

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

How to make a `<h:selectOneMenu>` unselectable/unchangeable. but still it should be submitted. 
It should be shown only for user reference.
If we use `disabled=true` it will not be submitted.

otherthan disabled how to make select one menu unchangeable ?

Comment: You can use a hidden component that will be bound to the `<h:selectOneMenu>` selected value.

Answer (score 0):

just use partialsubmit="true" along with disabled="true" it wil submitt the value

Answer (score 0):

Just disable it and provide the value in a hidden input.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}" disabled="true">...</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.value}" />
```